# Dynamic Right sizing for TCP implementation in linux

Tags: kernel

Is Dynamic Right Sizing(DRS) implemented in linux kernel(3.4 and above) by default?.In this link(http://public.lanl.gov/radiant/software/drs.html) patches for kernel 2.4.23 and 2.4.8 are available but nothing is mentioned about later versions of kernel. If it is not implemented by default in later versions of kernel can someone please direct me in the right direction to get it  installed(or implemented) in the later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think DRS is implemented. Looking at tot Linux tree:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L482

Answer (score -1):

The linux kernel auto tunes the TCP receive buffer size.

tcp_moderate_rcvbuf (Boolean; default: enabled; since Linux 2.4.17/2.6.7)
If enabled, TCP performs receive buffer auto-tuning, attempting to automatically size the buffer (no greater than tcp_rmem) to match the size required by the path for full throughput.

Source: http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp

Comment: did you answer the question? Is DRS implemented?

Comment: I think I did, but from your downvote I gather that you think I did not. No big deal, that's what the voting system is for :-)